# When Back Button Pressed activity doesn't return to Parent

Tags: android

Sorry for the answer but I have been searching all around the net for 2 days and still haven't managed to solve my problem.

I start a sub activity from the Main ( launcher activity ) with startActivity() . I have declared in the manifest that the parent of the second is the main Activity. My code onBackPressed in sub-activity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

The sub-activity finishes, but the main-parent activity is not shown. It goes back to Menu.

Comment: Why are you overriding `onBackPressed()` ? Dont do that...it will return you to the calling activity when you press the back button by default..

Comment: I have checked it, and it doesn't. It also goes to the Menu...
In addition, I have read in Google Docs that when an Activity is called, the calling Activity is paused. But I have seen that my Main Activity is destroyed... I can't figure it out at all.

Comment: yes..the `onPause()` is called..are you sure that you are not calling `finish()` after the new `intent` has been created..?

Answer (score 0):

use code like this

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
   super. onBackPressed();
}
```